# which language / platform doesn't have a fixed stack size?

Tags: stack, stack-size

does some language or platform not have a fixed size of stack and therefore not easy to overflow?  I remember using C on UNIX, the stack was difficult to overflow while back in the days of Win 3.1, the stack was very easy to overflow.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53827/checking-available-stack-size-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "stack" you mean any old stack, most languages do-- Java has a [stack](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) class limited only by memory. More likely you mean the call stack, in which case the biggest example I can think of is [Stackless Python](http://www.stackless.com/), which, to my understanding, uses a pure-python memory-limited stack (like Java's) as the call stack for Python code, rather than using C's call stack.

Answer (score 1):

this is a question of the practical vs the theoretical. the stack of a lisp interpreter is limited only by available memory

in scheme and other languages that implement tail recursion, a tail recursive function would have an infinite stack

Comment: A tail recursive function with the associated iterative optimization doesn't even go on the stack, as far as I know. If you define "stack" as related to calling functions, as an abstraction, that statement is true, but I wouldn't use that abstraction, since it's not particularly helpful. I didn't get the impression that that definition was normal, either.

Comment: can't C on UNIX / Solaris also have a stack size limited only by the physical memory?

Comment: I recall C had/has a stack segment size that is a kernel param

Comment: Devin, good question about whether a tail recursive function would use a stack. I implemented a scheme interpreter and yes, there is a stack frame. The difference is in the return action, with a tail recursive function there is a tail-return which overwrites the existing frame, so the stack used by that function has only a single frame.

Answer (score 0):

Mac Systems 6, 7, and 8 had call stacks that could grow without artificial limit.

It also has no guaranteed way to detect a stack--heap collision, and could get you into all kinds of trouble that way...