# Stack Size Estimation

Tags: c++, c, embedded, stack, static-analysis

In multi-threaded embedded software (written in C or C++), a thread must be given enough stack space in order to allow it to complete its operations without overflowing.  Correct sizing of the stack is critical in some real-time embedded environments, because (at least in some systems I've worked with), the operating system will NOT detect this for you.

Usually, the stack size for a new thread (other than the main thread) is designated at the time that thread is created (i.e. in an argument to pthread_create() or the like).  Often, these stack sizes are hard-coded to values that are known to be good at the time the code was originally written or tested.

However, future changes to the code often break the assumptions on which the hard-coded stack sizes were based, and one fateful day, your thread enters one of the deeper branches of its call graph and overflows the stack -- bringing down the whole system or silently corrupting memory.

I have personally seen this problem in the case where code executed in the thread declares struct instances on the stack.  When the struct is augmented to hold additional data, the stack size inflates accordingly, potentially allowing stack overflows to occur.  I imagine this could be a huge problem for established codebases where the full effects of adding fields to a structure cannot be known immediately (too many threads/functions to find all the places where that struct is used).

Since the usual response to "stack sizing" questions is "they're not portable", let's assume that the compiler, operating system, and processor are all known quantities for this investigation.  Let's also assume recursion isn't used, so we're not dealing with the possibility an "infinite recursion" scenario.

What are some reliable ways to estimate the necessary stack size for a thread?  I'd prefer methods that are offline (static analysis) and automatic, but all ideas are welcome.

Comment: Potential duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924430/, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/389219/

Comment: Being a novice in this area, I have to ask: wouldn't the most likely first step be to eliminate the use of structs as automatic variables? A pointer's size is not going to change no matter how much the struct it points to does. And an explicit request for memory (rather than the assumption that stack space is available) will allow the code to handle the case where memory is not available.

Comment: or even better, the struct on the stack should store little more than the pointer to dynamically allocated memory. That way you get the best of both worlds: Automatic lifetime management because it's on the stack, and everything that takes more than a few bytes can be heap-allocated to save on stack space.

Comment: @mcl: in C++, you could work with scoped_ptr, but in C you would have dynamic memory management, which doesn't help.  I do agree that stack containers (arrays) should be avoided, so in C++ STL-containers help.

Comment: @mcl In embedded software, explicitly requesting (dynamically) memory (e.g. malloc) comes with its own set of problems--such as heap fragmentation over long run times. In most cases, any such failure to allocate memory would be an unacceptable failure of the product, not one that can be usefully "handled by the code". But still--static allocation of memory could be considered instead of stack. But in many systems, in terms of overall memory usage, changing from stack variables to static variables would probably actually put you behind.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers!  It seems the most prevalent way to perform an offline static-analysis-based estimation is to use proprietary tools :-/.  I'd hoped that with this being such a universal concern that there would be some best practices out there that I hadn't heard of yet.  At least it makes me feel better that I'm not the only one who's resorted to the "painting the stack" approach.  An interesting idea is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/389219/how-to-determine-maximum-stack-usage/389305#389305, which suggests defining a custom function prologue to record the stack depth.

Comment: Yet another thread that deals with this at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424635/is-there-a-programmatic-way-to-check-stack-corruption/1426099 . My answer was particularly goof ;)

Comment: In Windows, I found [stackoverflow.com/questions/199747/how-to-detect-possible-potential-stack-overflow-problems-in-a-c-c-program][1] to be quite useful.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199747/how-to-detect-possible-potential-stack-overflow-problems-in-a-c-c-program

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Runtime-Evaluation**

An online method is to paint the complete stack with a certain value, like 0xAAAA (or 0xAA, whatever your width is). Then you can check how large the stack has maximally grown in the past by checking how much of the painting is left untouched.

Have a look at [this](http://www.netrino.com/Embedded-Systems/How-To/Malloc-Free-Dynamic-Memory-Allocation) link for an explanation with illustration.

The advantage is that it's simple. A disadvantage is that you cannot be certain that your stack size won't eventually exceed the amount of used stack during your testing.

**Static Evaluation**

There are some static checks and I think there even exists a hacked gcc version that tries to do this. The only thing I can tell you is that static checking is very difficult to do in the general case.

Also have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141498/what-open-source-c-static-analysis-tools-are-available) question.

Comment: I am a novice in this area, could u please explain this a bit more??

Comment: I've added a link to a site which explains the dynamic method a bit more in detail.

Answer (score 12):

You can use a static analysis tool like [StackAnalyzer](http://www.absint.com/stackanalyzer/), if your target fits the requirements.

Comment: +1 I would have pointed out that StackAnalyzer solves the "not portable" problem by working at the binary level.

Comment: Well, if your processor is not supported, you have the "not portable" problem again.

Answer (score 5):

If you want spend significant money you can use a commercial static analysis tool like Klocwork. Although Klocwork is primarily aimed at detecting software defects and security vulnerabilities. However, it also has a tool called 'kwstackoverflow' that can be used to detect stack overflow within a task or thread. I'm using for the embedded project that I work on, and I have had positive results. I don't think any tool like this is perfect, but I believe these commericial tools are very good. Most of the tools I have come across struggle with function pointers. I also know that many compiler vendors like Green Hills now build similar functionality right into their compilers. This is probably the best solution because the compiler has intimate knowledge of all the details needed to make accurate decisions about the stack size.

If you have the time, I'm sure you can use a scripting language to make your own stack overflow analysis tool. The script would need to identify the entry point of the task or thread, generate a complete function call tree, and then calculate the amount of stack space that each function uses. I suspect there are probably free tools available that can generate a complete function call tree so that should make it easier. If you know the specifics of your platform generating the stack space each function uses can be very easy. For example, the first assembly instruction of a PowerPC function often is the store word with update instruction that adjusts the stack pointer by the amount needed for the function. You can take the size in bytes right from the first instruction which makes determining the total stack space used relatively easy.

These types of analysis will all give you an approximation of the worst case upper bound for stack usage which is exactly what you want to know. Of course, pundits (like the ones I work with) might complain that you're allocating too much stack space, but they are dinosaurs that don't care about good software quality :)

One other possibility, although it doesn't calculate stack usage would be to use the memory management unit (MMU) of your processor (if it has one) to detect stack overflow. I have done this on VxWorks 5.4 using a PowerPC. The idea is simple, just put a page of write protected memory at the very top of your stack. If you overflow, a processor execption will occur and you will quickly be alerted to the stack overflow problem. Of course, it doesn't tell you by how much you need to increase the stack size, but if your good with debugging exception/core files you can at least figure out the calling sequence that overflowed the stack. You can then use this information to increase your stack size appropriately.

-djhaus

Comment: Thanks for the comment about kwstackoverflow.  I found out that my company actually had a license for kwstackoverflow, so I tried using it on an existing project.  Unfortunately, after many hours of experimenting, I found that kwstackoverflow doesn't support tracing C++ virtual function calls, which makes it almost useless (in my opinion) for object-oriented C++ code. See [my post on the klocwork forums](http://developer.klocwork.com/community/forums/klocwork-general/general-discussion/several-problems-kwstackoverflow). Perhaps this will be supported some day.  Still a neat tool for C, though.

Answer (score 4):

Not free, but [Coverity](http://www.coverity.com) does static analysis of the stack.

Comment: Stack analysis is platform-specific. On what platforms can Coverity do static stack analysis?

Comment: I'm not an expert, but you should tell Coverity to warn when chunks over a certain size is added to the stack and when the total stack is more than a certain size.  I don't think he mimics actual stack-usage.  I could be wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Static (off-line) stack checking is not as difficult as it seems.  I have implemented it for our embedded IDE ([RapidiTTy](http://www.tte-systems.com/overview)) — it currently works for ARM7 (NXP LPC2xxx), Cortex-M3 (STM32 and NXP LPC17xx), x86 and our in-house MIPS ISA compatible FPGA soft-core.

Essentially we use a simple parse of the executable code to determine the stack usage of each function.  Most significant stack allocation is done at the start of each function; just be sure to see how it alters with different optimisation levels and, if applicable, ARM/Thumb instruction sets, etc.  Remember also that tasks usually have their own stacks, and ISRs often (but not always) share a separate stack area!

Once you have the usage of each function, it's fairly easy to build up a call-tree from the parse and calculate the maximum usage for every function.  Our IDE generates schedulers (effective thin RTOSes) for you, so we know exactly which functions are being designated as 'tasks' and which are ISRs, so we can tell the worst-case usage for each stack area.

Of course, these figures are almost always over the **actual** maximum.  Think of a function like `sprintf` that can use a *lot* of stack space, but varies enormously depending on the format string and parameters that you provide.  For these situations you can also use dynamic analysis — fill the stack with a known value in your startup, then run in the debugger for a while, pause and see how much of each stack is still filled with your value (high watermark style testing).

Neither approach is perfect, but combining both will give you a fairly good picture of what the real-world usage is going to be like.

Answer (score 2):

As discussed in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389219/), a common technique is to initialise the stack with a known value and then to run the code for a while and see where the pattern stops.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an offline method but on the project that I am working on we have a debug command that reads the high water mark on all of the task stacks within the application.  This outputs a table of the stack usage for each task and the amount of headroom available.  Checking this data after a 24 hour run with lots of user interaction gives us some confidence that the defined stack allocations are "safe".

This works using the well tried technique of filling the stacks with a known pattern and assuming that the only way that this can be re-written is by the normal stack usage, although if it is being written by any other means a stack overflow is the least of your worries!

Comment: The caveats of a 24-hour run are (1) the run should give good code coverage, and/or (2) the un-covered code doesn't use substantially more stack.

Comment: I agree with both of these caveats.  In my situation and product this coverage is provided by the "user" interaction both real and simulated.

Answer (score 2):

We tried to solve this problem on an embedded system at my work.  It got crazy, there is just too much code (both our own and 3rd party frameworks) to get any reliable answer.  Luckily, our device was Linux based so we fell back to the standard behavior of giving every thread 2mb and letting the virtual memory manager optimize the use.

Our one issue with this solution was one of the 3rd party tools performed an `mlock` on its entire memory space (ideally to improve performance).  This caused all 2mb of stack for each thread of its threads (75-150 of them) to be paged in.  We lost half of our memory space to until we figured it out and commented out the offending line.

Sidenote: Linux's virtual memory manager(vmm) allocates RAM in 4k chunks.  When a new thread asks for 2MB of address space for its stack, the vmm assigns bogus memory pages to all but the top most page.  When the stack grows into bogus page the kernel detects a page fault and swaps the bogus page with a real one, (which consumes another 4k of actual RAM).  This way a thread's stack can grow to any size it needs (as long as it's less than 2mb) and the vmm will ensure only a minimal amount of memory is used.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from some of the suggestions already done I would like to point out that often in embedded systems you have to control stack usage tightly because you have to keep the stack size at a reasonable size.

In a sense, using stack space is a bit like allocating memory but without an (easy) way to determine if your allocation succeeded so not controlling stack usage will result in a forever struggle to figure out why your system is again crashing. So, for instance, if you system allocates memory for local variables from the stack, either allocate that memory with malloc() or, if you can't use malloc() write your own memory handler (which is a simple enough task).

No-no:

```
void func(myMassiveStruct_t par)
{
  myMassiveStruct_t tmpVar;
}
```

Yes-yes:

```
void func (myMassiveStruct_t *par)
{
  myMassiveStruct_t *tmpVar;
  tmpVar = (myMassiveStruct_t*) malloc (sizeof(myMassicveStruct_t));
}
```

Seems pretty obvious but often isn't - especially when you can't use malloc().

Of course you will still have problems, so this is just something to help but doesn't solve your problem. It will, however, help you estimate the stack size in the future, since once you have found a good size for your stacks and if you then, after some code modifications, again run out of stack space you can detect a number of bugs or other problems (too deep call stacks for one).

Comment: So you propose using heap instead of stack in embedded applications?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure, but I think this may also be done. If you have a jtag port exposed, you can connect to Trace32 and check the maximum stack usage. Though for this, you will have to give an initial pretty big arbitrary stack size.