# How can a preallocated OutOfMemoryError truthfully implement Throwable.getStackTrace if thrown twice?

Tags: java, out-of-memory

This is a follow up question to [What happens when there's insufficient memory to throw an OutOfMemoryError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9261705/what-happens-when-theres-insufficient-memory-to-throw-an-outofmemoryerror/9261931)

My question is the following: If an `OutOfMemoryError` is preallocated (to avoid the situation of having insufficient memory for the `OutOfMemoryError` object) and the JVM has to throw this type of error two times or more, then how can the preallocated object truthfully implement the `getStackTrace` method?

If the same object is reused, then one of the objects will most likely have an invalid `getStackTrace`, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 4):

The key to the answer lies in the contract to [`Throwable.getStackTrace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getStackTrace%28%29):

> Some virtual machines may, under some circumstances, omit one or more stack frames from the stack trace. In the extreme case, a virtual machine that has **no stack trace information concerning this throwable is permitted to return a zero-length array from this method**.

The `OutOfMemoryError` thrown is in fact not necessarily a preallocated one. If it has enough memory to allocated a new `OutOfMemoryError` with a proper stack trace it will. But if it hasn't got memory it will use a preallocated one with **no** stack trace information. Such preallocated object can therefor be **reused** if another `OutOfMemoryError` needs to be thrown.

---

Modifying  [the (best) answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9265014/271357) to the question you mentioned explains what is going on:

```
private static void test(OutOfMemoryError o) {
    try {
        for (int n = 1; true; n += n) {
            int[] foo = new int[n];
        }
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
        System.out.println("Stack trace length=" + e.getStackTrace().length + 
                           ", object id=" + System.identityHashCode(e));
        if (e == o)
            System.out.println("Got the same OutOfMemoryError twice (abort)");
        else
            test(e);
    }
}

public static void main (String[] args) {
    test(null);
}
```

Output:

```
Stack trace length=2, object id=1743911840
Stack trace length=3, object id=2136955031
Stack trace length=4, object id=903470137
Stack trace length=5, object id=1607576787
Stack trace length=0, object id=2103957824 <--- new object cannot be allocated
Stack trace length=0, object id=2103957824 <--- same object reused
Got the same OutOfMemoryError twice (abort)
```

Answer (score 0):

As can be seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29764066/350692) to the other question the HotSpot JVM will actually pre-allocate `OutOfMemoryErrors` without any stack trace as well as a number of them with pre-allocated space to fill in a stack trace.