# What happens when there is no memory to construct an OutOfMemoryException in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, clr

I found that `System.Exception` requires many memory allocation(many `String`s, even `IDictionary`). What happens when there is no enough memory to construct an `OutOfMemoryException`?

After searching, I found a similar question: [What happens when there's insufficient memory to throw an OutOfMemoryError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9261705/what-happens-when-theres-insufficient-memory-to-throw-an-outofmemoryerror) Does CLR behave like that?

Comment: IIRC, the CLR also pre-allocates that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you (Cu2s) mentioned, the framework pre allocate some objects. The OutOfMemory is not the only one. StackOverflow of course is also needed.

See source [here](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/775003a4c72f0acc37eab84628fcef541533ba4e/src/vm/clrex.cpp#L508)

And also this [blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tess/2009/08/10/why-do-i-see-executionengineexception-stackoverflowexception-and-outofmemoryexception-on-the-heap-when-debugging-net-applications/)

You can see it yourself in WinDbg or some other tool.

For example when I'm running this code:

```
static void Main()
{
    Console.Read();
}
```

I see in the heap the following:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found the source code of [coreclr](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/775003a4c72f0acc37eab84628fcef541533ba4e/src/vm/clrex.cpp). It seems that the CLR preallocates some exception classes.