# How does Java create OutOfMemoryError object when there is no memory available

Tags: java, memory-management, out-of-memory, heap-memory

Java creates every object in the heap space.
And when the heap space is full, it will throw a 
 **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space.**

How does java allocate the memory and create the OutOfMemoryError object when there is no space in the heap?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9261931/3260495

Answer (score 0):

It will overwrite an object and allocate the exception.