# How to get the stack size of an existing .NET thread

Tags: .net, multithreading, stack

I want to find out the stack size of .NET thread pool threads in CLR 4.0. Any ideas?

Nick

Comment: Curious why you need this.. (or if it's an experiment)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53827/checking-available-stack-size-in-c) on SO.  Doesn't look promising.  Additionally, see [this link](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/conversation.aspx?messageid=29909854&threadid=29909843) from an MS guy on the issue.

Here's also an untested reference I [located](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/System/Windows__Programming/Q_10014490.html) that is in assembler:

---

```
// OK, let's go assembly:

DWORD dwStackSize; //size of current thread's stack
_asm {
     mov eax,fs:[4]
     sub eax,fs:[8]
     mov dwStackSize,eax
}

// Don't know how to do this on non-intel CPU's.
```

---

Good luck.  Also, be sure to ask yourself what you are doing that really needs this information and if there isn't another solution to your problem.